# llvm-general-pure fail at compilation

Tags: haskell, llvm, cabal

I want to install the "llvm-general" package from cabal. But the "llvm-general-pure" (dependencies) fail at compilation :

```
[19 of 28] Compiling LLVM.General.Internal.PrettyPrint ( src/LLVM/General/Internal/PrettyPrint.hs, dist/build/LLVM/General/Internal/PrettyPrint.o )

src/LLVM/General/Internal/PrettyPrint.hs:166:19: error:
    • The constructor ‘DataD’ should have 6 arguments, but has been given 5
    • In the pattern: DataD _ _ tvb cons _
      In the pattern: TyConI (DataD _ _ tvb cons _)
      In a case alternative: TyConI (DataD _ _ tvb cons _) -> (tvb, cons)
```

And some other error.

My configuration:

> ghc -> 8.0.1
>
> cabal-install -> 1.24.0.0

Any idea to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the `llvm-general-pure` claims to work for `base < 5`, it does not support the GHC 8.0 changes to template haskell. In particular, the `DataD` constuctor [used to take 5 arguments](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.10.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html#v:DataD), but [now takes 6](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.11.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html#v:DataD). I have created a [ticket](https://github.com/bscarlet/llvm-general/issues/171) on the project's GitHub page to bring this issue to the maintainer's attention.